# React native ble plx package all device list

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm scanning with ble plx package. How can I get the list of all devices. As the package scans continuously, it adds the same device to the list more than once. I'll be happy if you can help me

Comment: Is this happening on android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

In the scan method u can pass false to the allowDuplicates field and your issue will be resolved.

[More on that](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Bluetooth-Scanning)

For example:

```
  bleManager.startDeviceScan(
   [], false
  )
```

Comment: Hi, just tried this: manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => { and is okay, tried manager.startDeviceScan([], false (error, device) => { and fails, tried manager.startDeviceScan(null, false, (error, device) => { still fails. Error is java'lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap ... why does this stuff always have to be so hard.